# Inserting python variables into MySQL syntax problems

Tags: python, mysql, variables

Can someone tell me what's wrong with this Syntax?

```
>>>y = 14
>>> cursor.execute("INSERT INTO accounts VALUES ('Bobby', %s)", (y))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 477, in execute
    stmt = operation % self._process_params(params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 355, in      
_process_params
    "Failed processing format-parameters; %s" % err)
    mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing format-parameters; argument   
    2 to map() must support iteration
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`y` should be inside a tuple:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO accounts VALUES ('Bobby', %s)", (y, ))
```

FYI, `(y)` is not a tuple - it is an `int` in parenthesis, adding comma `(y,)` makes it a tuple with one element inside:

```
>>> y = 14
>>> type((y))
<type 'int'>
>>> type((y,))
<type 'tuple'>
```